# Deleted DB re Populate in MySql

Tags: mysql, rollback

I am In Deep Trouble..

I have lost my DB as by mistake Have deleted my DB from the Mysql Db,

So could someone help me in getting the Rollback of it.

Please help

Comment: If you didn't backup your database, there is no way you can retrieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to execute your most recent backup.

Comment: I didn't got any solution but just a lesson.. :( Thanks Anyways